# Ignite on Docker

Tags: docker, ignite

On Docker (`docker run -it --net=host  --expose=8098  -p 47100:8098 [other options] apacheignite/ignite-docker`), I started ignite-node(server mode) and I created cache (replicated) on this node.

Now from Intelij Idea I created another ignite-node(client mode) and I want to connect(find) node which is on docker,for getting already created cache.

> Note:docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100

On Ignitation start brings 'Failed to connect ' error.

My IntelliJ Ignite config is:

```
 <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="localPort" value="47100"/>
                    <!-- Setting up IP finder for this cluster -->
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                            <property name="shared" value="true"/>
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <!--
                                        Addresses and port range of the nodes from the first
                                        cluster.
                                        127.0.0.1 can be replaced with actual IP addresses or
                                        host names. Port range is optional.
                                    -->
                                    <value>192.168.99.100:8098</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
```

Comment: What is the question, or error you're trying to resolve?

Comment: Oh,I'am sorry.I forget write question.It's brings 'Failed to connect' error.
Whether  my  all configurations  is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the port opened via the `docker run`:

```
<value>192.168.99.100:47100</value>
```

Comment: And 8098 where to use? 8098  is'nt my container port number?

Comment: No, when you specified `-p 47100:8098` you mapped the port 8098 from your container to your physical machine, so your machine have a free port on 8098. If you `sudo netstat -laputen | grep 8098` there should be nothing visible

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot, I understood.But I have a question,in general where is mapped (8098) port  can used ?

Comment: If you `docker inspect` your container you will see it's IP. You can access with it